# Is there a way to intercept the websocket messages within an iFrame I am loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, websocket

I'm loading an iframe on my website that automatically connects to an WebSockets (from the website I'm getting the iframe).

I'm using React and I would like to intercept the messages that are coming through this WebSocket.

Is there a way to do it?